# JS - Generic Parse JSON Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JQ/JS function that creates an AJAX request, and returns a JSON result.

```
 function ajaxRequest(url, callback){
                        $.ajax({
                              url: "Data/"+url,
                              type : 'GET',
                              contentType: "application/json",
                              success: function( resp ) {
                                       callback(resp );
                                   }
                          });
                          }
```

Currently this passes the whole response to my callback function.

How can I parse this for just the JSON object.

Each JSON object is different, they are a single level object, but each with different parameter names.

I was wondering if there is a generic way to  pass just the json object.

Typically, I would use:

resp.ObjectName

but I want to make this generic, for instances where I do not have ObjectName.

Comment: What do you *want* to do with the JSON returned? If you simply want to output every single object of a single-level JSON then just loop through it using `$.each()`.

Comment: what does `console.log(resp)` give you?

Comment: @BrianGlaz  Object { readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 8 more… }

Comment: That is not my json response, that is the resp. I am looking for a way to just get the json.

Comment: try `resp.responseText` ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the `dataType` option instead of `contentType`:

```
function ajaxRequest(url, callback){
                        $.ajax({
                              url: "Data/"+url,
                              type : 'GET',
                              dataType: "json",
                              success: function( resp ) {
                                       callback(resp );
                                   }
                          });
                          }
```

Comment: This returns undefined.

Comment: Could you write how do you refer to `resp` in your `callback` function? (a line of code that gives `undefined`). You could also try to place at the beginning of your `callback` function (just for debug) the line `consol.log(JSON.stringify(resp))` (assuming `resp` is the argument). It should show you the exact result returned by ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$.parseJSON` for parsing json result:

```
function ajaxRequest(url, callback){
                    $.ajax({
                          url: "Data/"+url,
                          type : 'GET',
                          dataType: "json",
                          success: function( resp ) {
                             var response = $.parseJSON(resp)
                                   callback(response);
                               }
                      });
                      }
```

Comment: You don't need $.parseJSON.

Comment: You can use resp.ObjectName[i].key to return the corresponding value.